# Using times() ends in ResponseException "The repeat()-traversal was not defined"

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph, tinkerpop3

```
g.V(startVertex)
    .repeat(__.inE().outV())
    .until(__.hasId(targetVertex))
    .path()
    .by(T.label);
```

Im using Tinkerpop 3.6.1 in Java.
I get an timeout exception if between startVertex and targetVertex is no connection. To prevent this, according to https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#repeat-step I limited the repeat loop with `.times(4)` between  `.until()` and  `.path()`.

```
g.V(startVertex)
   .repeat(__.inE().outV())
   .until(__.hasId(targetVertex))
   .times(4)
   .path()
   .by(T.label);
```

But then it throws following exception:

> org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.ResponseException: The repeat()-traversal was not defined: RepeatStep(until([HasStep([~id.eq(327684264)])]),null,emit(false))

I also tried `.loops().is(4)` and placing both between `.repeat()` and `.until()` but that didn't change anything.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things to be aware of:

1. If the graph contains cycles you should use `simplePath` to avoid running "forever".
2. You never use `until` and `times` together, but you can use `loops`. I have pasted an example of all this put together below. Note the second `has` step I added. This is to handle the case where `loops` is 4, but you did not find the desired target.

```java
g.V(startVertex)
   .repeat(__.inE().outV().simplePath())
   .until(__.hasId(targetVertex).or().loops().is(4))
   .hasId(targetVertex)
   .path()
   .by(T.label);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. But I have a question. Isn't simplePath just returning a path without edges?(and of course ignoring double steps) So how does hasId() on a simple Path work? I used your coder btw without simplePath.

Comment: Actually `simplePath` works differently. It will filter out any paths that loop back on themselves. So `A->B->C` is OK but `A->B->C->B` is not.